# Exceptions raised in tomcat not caught by custom error page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

quite new to spring boot - currently testing a project with `2.2.4.RELEASE` and minimal configuration as currently trying out spring boot to see if it meets my needs.

I've disabled the white label errors page, got my own `error.html` with `thymeleaf` as templating.

The project will mainly be REST based, so the `error.html` will only really be served if they try access things via a browser/set accept header to something not supported etc., for everything else I have a Controller annotated with `@RestControllerAdvice` with various `@ExceptionHandler` for various things, this works for the most part.

However the issue I am having is if I cause an exception in tomcat, i.e. `curl -H -i https://localhost:8443/%5C\' -k` will cause a 400 Bad Request, which produces the built in tomcat error page (which I do not want, thankfully I have hid the stack trace and exception with:

```
server.error.include-stacktrace=never
server.error.include-exception=false
```

This exception never seems to propagate up to my exception handlers. I've read other questions that were similar but none of the suggestions have worked, and I am lost now. :-(

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On the web.xml you can trap these tomcat level error messages and show a page of your choice like below -

```
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/Error.html</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/Error.html</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>501</error-code>
        <location>/Error.html</location>
    </error-page>

  <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/Error.html</location>
    </error-page>
```

Comment: Was hoping not to revert to this method as been hoping to stick with spring boot configuration and embedded tomcat. But looks like web.xml will be only way at this point

Comment: ok. if you think this answer is correct then you can upvote it.